# ALSA issue playing multiple audio using mpg123 stretch (jessie was fine!) Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi3, pulseaudio, debian-stretch

I've been chasing this issue down for a few long (long) days and can now 100% reproduce but not sure actually whats causing the issue. This used to work 100% under jessie but not stretch (ive re-checked at I am right it works). Let me explain how to reproduce as it shows what I need to do (mixing tracks at the end for a smooth music transition - part of my project).
2 terminal ssh windows to your stretch raspberry pi 3B+
first window:
sudo /usr/bin/mpg123 -q -a hw:0,0 /media/musicfile1.mp3   #(now hear music ok)

second window:
sudo /usr/bin/mpg123 -q -a hw:0,0 /media/musicfile2.mp3   #(now hear music ok)

Now stop the first window music and try restarting it. The music jumps, buffers, clicks and basically goes wrong. You could have restarted the 2nd window all day long with no issues. As I say this works really well under jessie. This solution is out of the box (i.e. not changed alsa configurations / asource etc).
Can anyone else easily reproduce? Anyone any ideas? I know the issue is also with mplayer so it must be alsa related right (since pulseaudio is not in stretch by default). This is command line PI only (no GUI).

HELP, you could be my hero, I know you are out there!

Comment: So here are some combinations that i have tested. Could really do with some ideas :/
(The fails are as per my previous point, start music in window 1 (good), start music in window 2(good), stop and restart music in window 1 - then fails: -
1. Rasp 3B and jessie, all works fine
2. Rasp 3B with stretch - fails
3. Rasp 3B with rpi-update special (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q ... rry-pi-3-b) - fails
4. Rasp 3B+ with stretch - fails
5. Rasp 3B+ with rpi-update, performed on 3B first to allow boot, then move to 3B+ = fails

Any thoughts? Ideas of what to do next?

Comment: I've just burnt a brand new, latest stretch LITE to disk (2018-04-18-raspbian-stretch-lite.img), booted in Rasp 3B+
initial changes only install omxplayer, ssh enable, and also amixer cset numid=3 1 to get out of the 3.5mm
window 1: omxplayer -o local song.mp3 (plays good)
window 2: omxplayer -o local song.mo3 (plays good over the top of the other track)
go back to window 1. stop omxplayer (press q) and then restart it. Audio is then bad!
This is as much of "out of the box" that i can make it (no?)
I then added audio-pwm-mode=2, rebooted, and tried again. still bad :(

Comment: For information this is a confirmed bug. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=195178&start=50